# how to display image after success ajax process

Tags: javascript, ajax

i want to display an qrcode after i've submit data to the DB
and this is my code of submitting :

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
       $("input#submitmap").click(function() {
            var routedmap = 
                {
                 destination :destinationDB,
                 point: addressRoute

                };

            $.ajax({
              type: 'POST',
              url: 'addroutedmap.php',
              data: routedmap,
            success: function(data){


            }
            });
        });

    });
```

in the success function after submitted, i wanna display image of qrcode, here is the code of the image :

```
<img src="https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?
cht=qr&amp;chs=200x200&amp;chl=http://www.facebook.com"></img>
```

i've tried using  .show .html (+data+ ) and it doesn't work.
is there any idea or suggestion?

Comment: what exactly is in data?  is it that <img src=""></img> string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried this:

```
$('body').append('<img src="https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=qr&chs=200x200&chl=http%3a%2f%2fwww.facebook.com" />');
```

or:

```
$('#container').html('<img src="https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=qr&chs=200x200&chl=http%3a%2f%2fwww.facebook.com" />');
```

where `#container` is some DOM element to harbor your image.

or the way I prefer:

```
$('#container').html(
    $('<img/>', {
        src: 'https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=qr&chs=200x200&chl=http%3a%2f%2fwww.facebook.com',
        alt: ''
    })
);
```

Comment: The image tag ends with `/>` and not `</img>`

Comment: @tgt, if this post was helpful you might consider [marking it as answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) by clicking on the tick next to it.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#div_where_you_will_sho_qr_code').append(data.toString());
```